# Dataset for neurons in the brain?

Tags: data-request, biology

Is there any available dataset for the interaction of neurons in the brain? As I know the brain is composed of huge numbers of connected neurons. Also new neurons are added regularly and new connections are made as well. Is there a dataset that captures such evolving information/interactions about the brain?

I want the data of one brain with all the evolution of the brain over time. Like new neurons, which neurons made new connections with which neurons .. and so on.

Comment: Just to make it clear: All brains have a different set of neurons. What you want is recorded captures (instances), right?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul yes. I want the data of one brain with all the evolution of the brain over time. Like new neurons, which neurons made new connections with which neurons .. and so on.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul are you aware of a dataset for that?

Comment: I was just trying to improve the question. Unfortunately I don't know such a dataset :-/